# Adding hyperlinks to gridview encased in Ajax Accordion

Tags: ajax, gridview, hyperlink, accordion

In my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954361/hyperlink-in-gridview-binding-to-wrong-row-by-1) I got to adding hyperlinks to a gridview. Now I've encased the same gridview in an Ajax Accordion. Unfortunately, it rendered my method of adding hyperlinks useless cause the OnRowDataBound method returns the following error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'."

on the line:

`HyperLink nameHl = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];`

Now I've tried the:

`NavigateUrl='<%# "http://websitelink" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'`

way, but with the naming convention of the link's suffix and how I need to replace the black spaces with "+". this isn't really going to work for my project. Additionally, the website link may not always be the same, so I would rather have the hyperlink defined on server side than client side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

Client Side:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" Width="935px" 
 SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" OnItemDataBound="Accordion1_ItemDataBound" 
 CssClass="acc-content" HeaderCssClass="acc-header" HeaderSelectedCssClass="acc-selected" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="False">
 <HeaderTemplate>
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Rpt_Grouping") %>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hlbl_categoryID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Rpt_Grouping") %>' />
        <asp:GridView ID="accGvReportList" runat="server" RowStyle-BackColor="#ededed" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="accGvReportList_RowDataBound">
               <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Report Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#d1d1d1" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#777777">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:HyperLink ID="contentLink" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Report Description" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#d1d1d1" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#777777">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                   <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate></asp:Accordion>
```

Server Side:

```
        // binds the DB table to the grid inside the accordion tool 
    protected void Accordion1_ItemDataBound(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemType == AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemType.Content)
        {
            string listPath = "/subcat%";
            string categoryValue = ((HiddenField)e.AccordionItem.FindControl("hlbl_categoryID")).Value;
            DataTable dtReportList = objInfoDal.getReportListDetails(listPath, ddlFolders.SelectedValue.ToString(), categoryValue);

            GridView grd = new GridView();

            grd = (GridView)e.AccordionItem.FindControl("accGvReportList");
            grd.DataSource = dtReportList;
            grd.DataBind();

        }
    }

    // hyperlink binding by row for first column in gridview in the accordion tool
    protected void accGvReportList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Changes text in the first column into HyperLinks
        HyperLinkField nameLink = gvReportList.Columns[0] as HyperLinkField;

        string linkPath = "http://websitelink";
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //applies a unique suffix to the address depending on the link name
            HyperLink nameHl = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            string nameText = nameHl.Text;
            string linkSuffix = nameText.Replace(" ", "+");
            nameHl.NavigateUrl = linkPath + linkSuffix;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by replacing

```
HyperLink nameHl = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```

with

```
HyperLink nameHl = ((HyperLink)(e.Row.FindControl("contentLink")));
```

Solution credited to asp.net forum topic: [Convert a field in a code bound GridView to a hyperlink](http://forums.asp.net/t/1233865.aspx/1)